# Why might my time series plot look so distorted?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

I've created a plot using this code:

```
MERItemp <- ggplot(MERIInletWL_merge2, aes(x=DateTime,y=WLTemp_c)) +
geom_point(size = 0.001)+
labs(x=NULL, y="Water Temp") +
theme()+ggtitle("Meriweather Place Apartments")
MERItemp
```

The data frame that it is pulling data from appears very normal. It has a DateTime column and a column labeled "WLTemp_c" that has one corresponding water temperature ranging from roughly 5-25 degrees.

However, when I attempt to plot the data, this is what is produced:

[image]

I've never seen a plot like this. There is clearly an issue with the Y-axis as well as the plotting of the actual points. Any ideas?

Comment: please provide at least a subset of the actual data. You can use `dput(MERIInletWL_merge2)`  or, if it is too large, `dput(head(MERIInletWL_merge2))`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the WLTemp_c column was read in as characters rather than numbers so I ran the code below to fix it:

```
MERIOutletWL_merge2$WLTemp_c <- as.numeric(MERIOutletWL_merge2$WLTemp_c )
```